# Using Fetch instead of XMLHttpRequest in React Native

Tags: express, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest, react-native, fetch-api

I was trying to upload images to S3 from my react native app by following and adapting this guide by heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node

Essentially I am using the aws-sdk on my express.js backend to generate pre-signed request for uploading images to S3 from react native.

Everything works well, so then I tried to convert the XMLHttpRequests into fetch requests, which seem to be favoured by react native. After the conversion, the files are still being uploaded to S3, but when I click on the image links, then the images wouldn't not show properly, instead an empty square is shown:

[Empty square shown instead of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IZ2p.png)

More specifically it seems to be this piece of code conversion that causes it to happen:

From:

```
_uploadFile(file, signedRequest, url){
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('PUT', signedRequest);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
      if(xhr.status === 200){
        console.log("UPLOAD DONE");
      } else {
        alert('ERROR UPLOADING');
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send(file);
}
```

To:

```
_uploadFile(file, signedRequest, url) {
  let option = {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(file)
  }

  fetch(signedRequest, option)
    .then(res => console.log("UPLOAD DONE"))
    .catch(err => console.log("ERROR UPLOADING: ", err))
}
```

The file object being uploaded:

```
  {
    name: "profileImage",
    type: "image/jpeg",
    uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data, //just a base64 image string
    isStatic: true
  }
```

Could anyone shed some light on why this could be happening, or have had similar experiences? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your fetch example you put a JSON string in your body. It will be sent to S3 but it will not be interpreted as an image upload. You should be able to construct a [FormData](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Network/FormData.js) object yourself and pass it to fetch as the request body, but I think using XHR is the simpler option. According to [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/201#issuecomment-86267887) it's what Facebook does as well (the comment is over a year old).

If at all possible you should also try to use local URIs instead of passing Base64 encoded data. It takes quite a while to transfer a few MB of image data between JS and native.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I tried using FormData along with local URI as you suggested, but the result is still the same as before, and now S3 interprets the content type as multipart/form-datas

Comment: When does that transfer happen, Daniel? I have to integrate against a backend that expects base64 encoded images. Is it because JS has to read the images over the bridge to turn it into Base64?